# CGI horror short on Youtube--man crawls into his computer and is swarmed by crows

Tags: story-identification, horror

I know this isn't a typical feature movie/TV show so will be harder to identify.

There is an incredible CGI horror short that was on YouTube in 2008 about a guy who is working late, alone in the office or at his apartment (can't remember) crawls into his computer and there are tons of either ravens or crows that swarm him. Very eerie.

I showed it to my college roommate at the time who was in the art school and he was like holy crap, this is incredibly well done. I'd like to try to find it again if possible. I don't think there is any dialogue to look up and I've searched for combinations of ravens crows computer horror short movie, etc. and can't quite find it.

I bet it had over 1 million views though, it was that good.

Would be surprised if anyone gets it but had to at least try.

Comment: Did that guy somehow entered computer thorough the display or so? At what point ravens started to chase him?

Comment: Looking for this same video. Did anyone ever find it? I want to say it was called "6 o'clock" or something like that.

Comment: I think I saw it, think it was kind of BW horror...

Comment: Crows. Why did it have to be crows.